# Getting the reference for BufferedImage to and int[] problem

Tags: java, casting, integer, render, bufferedimage

So i've read the other posts on this topic but they doesn't help me, only suggests that you should use byte[] instead.

The problem is that im getting the exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.awt.image.DataBufferByte cannot be cast to class java.awt.image.DataBufferInt (java.awt.image.DataBufferByte and java.awt.image.DataBufferInt are in module java.desktop of loader 'bootstrap')

Where could the problem lie in not beeing able to cast the the bufferedImage data to BufferedDataInt??:
`pixels = ((DataBufferInt)(image.getRaster().getDataBuffer())).getData();`

Main class:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SwingMain extends Canvas{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    Bitmap sprite;
    
    JFrame frame;
    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 1080;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 960;
    private boolean running = false;
    private static final int imageWidth = 256;
    private static final int imageHeight= 256;
    private static int tick;
    BufferedImage imageAtlas;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    InputHandler inputHandler = new InputHandler(this);
    static int xp = 0;
    static int yp = 0;
    
    SwingMain()
    {
        // Frame
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        // Must be set for createBufferStrategy to work
        frame.add(this); 
        
        // Sets the canvas focus so it responds to keyboardEvents directly on startup
        this.requestFocusInWindow(); 
        
        imageAtlas = new BufferedImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        //Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(imageWidth, imageHeight);
        //imageAtlas.setRGB(0, 0, bitmap.w, bitmap.h, bitmap.pixels, 0, bitmap.w);
        try
        {
            imageAtlas = ImageIO.read(new File("Art.png"));
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("FILE FAILED");
        }
        
        bitmap = new Bitmap(imageAtlas);
        
        int width = imageAtlas.getWidth();
        int height= imageAtlas.getHeight(); 
        
        running = true;
        
    }
```

Bitmap class

````
import java.awt.image.*;

public class Bitmap {
    public int[] pixels;
    public int w, h;
    
    Bitmap(int w, int h, int[] pixels)
    {
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        this.pixels= pixels; 
    }
    
    Bitmap(BufferedImage image)
    {
        
        this.w = image.getWidth();
        this.h = image.getHeight();
        
        pixels = new int[w*h];
        
        // Cast the the DataBuffer in the image.getRaster() to a DataBufferInt type and extract the getData() from that. 
        System.out.println("Datatype: " + image.getRaster().getDataBuffer().getDataType());
        pixels = ((DataBufferInt)(image.getRaster().getDataBuffer())).getData();
        //image.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, pixels, 0, w);       
    }```
````

Comment: What is the point of this code? What are you trying to accomplish.? The BuffereidImage class already has a method that returns an Array on ints.

Comment: The _[DataBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/DataBuffer.html)_ returned is a _[DataBufferByte](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/DataBufferByte.html)_, and not a _[DataBufferInt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/DataBufferInt.html)_.  Is there any reason not to use a _byte_ array, over the _int_ array?

Comment: The assignment `imageAtlas = new BufferedImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);` is pointless as you are overwriting the value with `imageAtlas = ImageIO.read(new File("Art.png"));` right afterwards. So only when an `IOException` occurs, the image is guaranteed to have `TYPE_INT_ARGB`. Otherwise, it can be anything (whatever the ImageIO loader decides). Note that this also applies to the size of the `BufferedImage`; it will be whatever has been read from the PNG, entirely unrelated to the `imageWidth` and `imageHeight` variables used to initialize the unused empty image.

Comment: But i want to get a reference to the BufferedImage into an int[] so that i can manipulate what parts should be visible of the image before the g.DrawImage() occurs, but through the int[].

Comment: There are plenty of ways to modify a `BufferedImage`. There are also multiple ways to control the rendering, without modifying the `BufferedImage`. Why do you think that getting data as an `int[]` was the only way to achieve your goal?

Comment: “so that i can manipulate what parts should be visible of the image” Please explain this in more detail.  If you just want to draw a rectangular subsection of an image, there are much better ways to do it than altering the image itself.

Comment: Okay, but then can you point me in a direction  where I can draw multiple sprites from an atlas with one drawImage call?

Comment: As you can see, [the Graphics class has six drawImage methods](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics.html#method-summary).  I think you’ll find that the first two will do what you want:  you can specify the exact part of an image that you wish to draw.  Alternatively, you can call [getSubimage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage(int,int,int,int)) on your BufferedImage to create an image that uses the same pixel storage as the larger image, rather than a copy.

Comment: Allright i got it know, I realize where the problem is